# MSBuild does not evaluate property correctly

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have an `ItemGroup` which defines several values which should later be written to a file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_SomeValue Include="SomeInclude">
        <_Parameter1>%(PrintMe)</_Parameter1>
    </_SomeValue>
</ItemGroup>
```

`PrintMe` is defined previously. Its value should be printed in the end.

The lines to write to the file are built like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_LinesToWrite Include="Some First Line" />
    <_LinesToWrite Include="%(_SomeValue._Parameter1)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And are then written:

```
<WriteLinesToFile File="$(TheFile)" Lines="@(_LinesToWrite)" />
```

The problem is that the file does not contain the value of `PrintMe` at the end, but rather the literal string `%(PrintMe)`.
This means that the line `<_LinesToWrite Include="%(_SomeValue._Parameter1)" />` does not evaluate the property in `_Parameter1` and rather prints its literal content. How can I change that?

Comment: msbuild reads every [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#item-metadata) in parallel, which means simultaneously, so if you want to overwrite a metadata with another metadata, you have to specify an order.

Comment: Hi! It turns out that this is actually an error related to xbuild. I was able to get it to work for msbuild with your answer!

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MSBuild does not evaluate property correctly

**MSBuild** reads [each metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#item-metadata) **in parallel**, which means it is done at the same time, so the value of the first `metadata` cannot be read in another `metadata`.

**Therefore**, if you want to assign values between metadata, you must specify an order. For example, put another one to read the first metadata into a target.

Note: `%` reads a metadata and it should be with the name of the item at the same time.

For an example,

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FirstValue Include="FirstValue">
      <PrintMe>i am print me</PrintMe>
    </FirstValue>
 </ItemGroup>
```

To read the value of `PrintMe`, you should use `%(FirstValue.PrintMe)`.

Please refer to this and in my side, it can print the value of `PrintMe` item metadata.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <FirstValue Include="FirstValue">
            <PrintMe>i am print me</PrintMe>
        </FirstValue>
</ItemGroup>
    
  <Target Name="test123" AfterTargets="Build">
      <ItemGroup>
          <_SomeValue Include="SomeInclude">
              <_Parameter1>%(FirstValue.PrintMe)</_Parameter1>
          </_SomeValue>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
          <_LinesToWrite Include="Some First Line" />
          <_LinesToWrite Include="%(_SomeValue._Parameter1)" />
      </ItemGroup>
        
      <Message Importance="high" Text="%(_SomeValue._Parameter1)">
    </Message>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="test.txt" Lines="@(_LinesToWrite)">
    </WriteLinesToFile>
  </Target>
```

[image]